# How to InsertOrSelect with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework v6 and I'm trying to make sure that I can perform an atomic Insert or Select the record if it doesn't already exist so that in a farm of servers (or multiple threads) I can guarantee that I don't get a unique key constraint violation.

I have a simple example with a table like this and a corresponding simple Model with the 2 properties.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NewItem]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_NewItem] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [IX_NewItem] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ( [Name] ASC)
)
```

When I write my Entity Framework code, I cannot guarantee that the object doesn't get inserted after the `.Any` returns false.

```
using (var myContext = new MyContext())
{
    using (var transaction = myContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        if (!myContext.NewItems.Any(item => item.Name == identifier))
        {
            var newItem = new NewItem { Name = identifier };
            myContext.NewItems.Add(newItem);

            try
            {
                var result = myContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Print(ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }
        }

        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

If I was to perform this same code using a direct SQL statement via a `SqlCommand` object, this is what I would use and as far as I can tell it always works.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT ID FROM NewItem WHERE Name = @name)) " +
            " BEGIN " + 
            " INSERT INTO NewItem VALUES (@name) " +
            " SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ID " +
            " END " +
            " ELSE " +
            " BEGIN " +
            " SELECT ID FROM NewItem WHERE Name = @name " +
            " END";
        var nameParam = new SqlParameter("@name", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 40);
        nameParam.Value = Name;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(nameParam);

        connection.Open();
        var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        connection.Close();

        Id = Convert.ToInt32(result);
    }
}
```

Is there some way with Entity Framework that I can perform the same operation as my raw `SqlCommand` so that if the record doesn't exist it gets inserted and if it already exists, I just get the one that is there in an atomic operation?

To demonstrate this is some of the threading code that I've used to simulate multiple servers.

```
private static ExecutionMode mode;
private static ManualResetEventSlim wait;
private static string identifier;

private enum ExecutionMode
{
    None = 0,
    Entityframework,
    RawSql
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Comment out the relevant item to test
    //mode = ExecutionMode.RawSql;
    mode = ExecutionMode.Entityframework;

    wait = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
    identifier = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    var threads = new List<Thread>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        var t = new Thread(RunCreate);
        threads.Add(t);
        t.Start();
    }

    wait.Set();

    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        var t = threads[i];
        t.Join();
    }
}

private static void RunCreate()
{
    wait.Wait();
    switch (mode)
    {
        case ExecutionMode.Entityframework:
            {
                //perform the Entityframework code above
            }
            break;
        case ExecutionMode.RawSql:
            {
                var i = new NewItem { Name = identifier };
                i.InsertOrSelect(); //This is just using the code for the raw SQL Statements
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Exceptions experienced with the Entityframework, displaying ex.Message looping through the exception->innerexception until innerexception is null

With Default Transaction Isolation Level

```
BeginTransaction()
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' 
  occurred in EntityFramework.dll
An error occurred while updating the entries. 
  See the inner exception for details.
An error occurred while updating the entries. 
  See the inner exception for details.
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'IX_NewItem'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.NewItem'. 
  The duplicate key value is (f32c6a59-1462-49c3-85e2-5126c96ad484).
```

With Serializable tranaction Isolation

```
BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable) 
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' 
  occurred in EntityFramework.dll 
Transaction (Process ID 59) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of these are guaranteed to work. The piece that you are missing is [Transaction Isolation Level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx).

The SQL Server default isolation level is `READ COMMITTED`. This has only minimal locking protections. It means that it is possible for another command to insert the new item after your `IF` condition is evaluated but before the new row is inserted. The raw SQL server command is *much* less likely to encounter this scenario because it is processed without a round-trip between the commands: there is less time for another server to interfere.

If you set the isolation level to Serializable then you are guaranteed to either insert the item or select the existing item. In Entity Framework your code will look like this:

```
using (var myContext = new MyContext())
{
    using (var transaction = myContext.Database.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable))
    {
        if (!myContext.NewItems.Any(item => item.Name == identifier))
        {
            var newItem = new NewItem { Name = identifier };
            myContext.NewItems.Add(newItem);
            try
            {
                var result = myContext.SaveChanges();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Print(ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }
        }
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried adding the `System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable` to the BeginTransaction and i get the same result with the Violation.

Comment: Does this violation occur when the code is only running on one server, in one thread? Is the code you posted the exact code you are using? I assume that it is modified to show only the necessary details.

Comment: The violation does *not* occur in a single thread/server scenario

Comment: Not sure what's happening then. I would try debugging and using SQL Server Profiler. Perhaps just run two instances with 1 thread each and strategically debug to see what's going on. Also, can you post the exception that you're getting?

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. The deadlock exception with "Serializable" isolation is an entirely different issue. I don't entirely understand why the deadlock is occurring, but I'm not a SQL expert. You might be able to remedy the deadlock by making `Name` the primary key. This could allow SQL Server to place locks more efficiently. Alternatively, you could just "Rerun the transaction" as the error message indicates.